# D3.js gantt redraw with zoom not erase old tasks from code, and mouseevent on tasks not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gantt-chart

I try use this: http://codepen.io/Pau/pen/FKzEa d3.js gantt chart with zoom and scroll, but I have problems. This is my version, where I added tasks in code, mousevent and line:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgVdgm

When I added task use button, scroll and zoom working good. But when I added tasks in code:

```
var tasks = [{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 01:36:45 EST 2012"),
          "endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 02:36:45 EST 2012"),
          "taskName":"E Job",
          "status":"RUNNING"}, 
        {"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 03:36:45 EST 2012"),
          "endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 04:36:45 EST 2012"),
          "taskName":"E Job",
          "status":"RUNNING"}
        ];
```

I see two tasks, but when I scroll or zoom, this tasks not erase. Why?

Problem two is when I try add mouseevent to tasks:

```
svg.selectAll(".chart")
  .data(tasks, keyFunction).enter()
  .append("rect")
    .attr("rx", 5)
    .attr("ry", 5)
    .attr("class", function(d){ return 
tatus[d.status] || "bar"; }) 
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("transform", rectTransform)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return 5; }) // y.rangeBand(); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return (x(d.endDate) - x(d.startDate)); })
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    alert("abcd");
        });
```

Event doesen't work. I think problem is css class:

```
.pane {
  cursor: move;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

When i change pointer-events to auto, mouseevent work, but scrollable gantt not work... How set this property that to work both?

Third problem is drawline. I add drawline method:

```
 var drawLine = function(svg){
var testDate = new Date("Sun Dec 09 00:36:45 EST 2012");
  svg.append("line").attr(
    {
      "class":"horizontalGrid",
      "x1" : x(testDate),
      "y1" : 0,
      "x2" : x(testDate),
      "y2" : height,
      "fill" : "none",
      "shape-rendering" : "crispEdges",
      "stroke" : "red",
      "z-index" : "550",
      "stroke-width" : "2px"
    });
```

};

and invoke this in gantt function. Line is draw, but when I scroll my chart, line not move. How to fix it?

Please see in this page: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgVdgm all three problems.